# show filter section after going under subcategory of main category in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want show filter section under only subcategory of product.

Reference site is below. How can I do? Is there any plugin for that?

Reference Site is: https://www.q-railing.com/en-ie/glass-railings/

Please help me.

Comment: I have never seen any straight forward plugin for this but it can be done with calculating whethber the category is a leaf category or not.

And truely speaking that whole thing can't be described here. You should try the coding and if you are stuck somewhere we will be glad to you.....but to solve a project is not possible here....

Comment: Thanks Alice for response. I resolved this issue.